# Can't use iCloud 2FA without iPhone

Tags: iphone, icloud, android

So I recently switched from iPhone to Samsung and I have
some things on my iCloud account. Every time I want to
sign in in a new device, iCloud asks me to use the 2FA
thing. Because I now have an Samsung, I can't sign in.
Hence, I'll have to sign in with the device while bringing my
iPhone every time I want to sign in. Any ideas?

Comment: You can click "Didn't Receive Code" and choose to get an SMS

Comment: Based from [the official help article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915), I think you have to remove your iPhone from the "Trusted devices" and use "Trusted phone numbers" instead.